# python import .so file error: File not found

Tags: python, c++

made a libtorrent.so in mips and scp it to my router, also i made a python that cross compile by myself too.
on the mips board, the python is running ok, but when i use `import libtorrent as lt`, it will return the import Error: File not found.

```
root@xxx:/tmp/python# ./python bt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bt.py", line 3, in <module>
    import libtorrent as lt
ImportError: File not found
```

if the libtorrent.so is not exist, the error will become `import Error:no module named libtorrent`...  so I think these two error is different
I've already put the libtorrent.so into PYTHONPATH
What should I do to make it OK?

this some of the bt.py,it runs in Ubuntu OK,but on the mips board the python can't import the libs

```
import libtorrent as lt
import sys
import os
import time
from optparse import OptionParser
import socket
import struct
import fcntl

    def get_interface_ip(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s',
                            ifname[:15]))[20:24])
def ip2long(ip):
    return reduce(lambda a,b:(a<<8)+b,[int(i) for i in ip.split('.')])
def get_wan_ip_address():
    interfaces = set(['eth0', 'eth1', 'eth2', 'eth3', 'em1', 'em2', 'em3', 'em4'])
    ip = ''
    for i in interfaces:
        try:
            ip = get_interface_ip(i)
            if (ip2long(ip) < ip2long('10.0.0.0') or ip2long(ip) > ip2long('10.255.255.255')) \
                and (ip2long(ip) < ip2long('172.16.0.0') or ip2long(ip) > ip2long('172.33.255.255')) \
                and (ip2long(ip) < ip2long('192.168.0.0') or ip2long(ip) > ip2long('192.168.255.255')):
                return ip
        except:
            pass

    return ip

def make_torrent(path, save):
    fs = lt.file_storage()
    lt.add_files(fs, path)
    if fs.num_files() == 0:
        print 'no files added'
        sys.exit(1)

    input = os.path.abspath(path)
    basename = os.path.basename(path)
    t = lt.create_torrent(fs, 0, 4 * 1024 * 1024)

    t.add_tracker("http://10.0.1.5:8760/announce")
    t.set_creator('libtorrent %s' % lt.version)

    lt.set_piece_hashes(t, os.path.split(input)[0], lambda x: sys.stderr.write('.'))
    sys.stderr.write('\n')

    save = os.path.dirname(input)
    save = "%s/%s.torrent" % (save, basename)
    f=open(save, "wb")
    f.write(lt.bencode(t.generate()))
    f.close()
    print "the bt torrent file is store at %s" % save


def dl_status(handle):
    while not (handle.is_seed()):
        s = handle.status()

        state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata', \
                'downloading', 'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating', 'checking fastresume']
        print '\ractive_time: %d, %.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kb/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d, seeds: %d) %s' % \
                (s.active_time, s.progress * 100, s.download_rate / 1000, s.upload_rate / 1000, \
                s.num_peers, s.num_seeds, state_str[s.state]),
        sys.stdout.flush()

        time.sleep(1)
def seed_status(handle, seedtime=100):
    seedtime = int(seedtime)
    if seedtime < 100:
        seedtime = 100
    while seedtime > 0:
        seedtime -= 1
        s = handle.status()

        state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata', \
                'downloading', 'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating', 'checking fastresume']
        print '\rseed_time: %d, %.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kb/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d, seeds: %d) %s' % \
                (s.active_time, s.progress * 100, s.download_rate / 1000, s.upload_rate / 1000, \
                s.num_peers, s.num_seeds, state_str[s.state]),
        sys.stdout.flush()

        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: can you post some code please?

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire this is the head of bt.py                                      import libtorrent as lt
import sys
import os
import time
from optparse import OptionParser
import socket
import struct
import fcntl

def get_interface_ip(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s',
                            ifname[:15]))[20:24])
def ip2long(ip):
    return reduce(lambda a,b:(a<<8)+b,[int(i) for i in ip.split('.')])

Comment: I can't understand anything. Can you please post this code on the question with formatting to be able to understand better your code? As you know reading python without being able to see identation is pretty difficult

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire  sorry ,I first use this site...the code is on the question and formatting

Comment: Did you try adding current path to PYTHONPATH? If not, you can do it programmatically: `import sys sys.path.append('.') import libtorrent as lt`

Comment: @roymustang86 I tried that already..but it doesn't work